# How does SQLAlchemy's append method work for association tables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering how does append method work in sqlalchemy when applied to many-to-many relationship case. It's unclear for me looking at results of my flow and I couldn't find anything in their documentation. In short, I want to track the history of tasks using three objects: Task, Status - ORM objects - and task_history - the association table. Here's my implementation (for clarity I don't include all imports etc.) using sqlite as the database:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

task_history = Table(
    "task_history",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("task_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tasks.id")),
    Column("status_id", Integer, ForeignKey("statuses.id")),
    Column("status_from", DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now()),
    Column("status_to", DateTime(timezone=True)),
    
    UniqueConstraint("task_id", "status_id", name="unique_tid_sid")
)


class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = "statuses"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    status = relationship("Status", secondary=task_history)
```

I create a new task and append a status this way:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///instance/test.db")
session = Session(engine)

task = Task("my_new_task")
status_created = session.query(Status).filter_by(name="created").first()
task.status.append(status_created)
session.add(task)
session.commit()
```

This works fine, a new record is inserted to the task_history table. However, when I run the following code nothing happens:

```
task = session.query(Task).filter_by(name="my_new_task").first()
task.status.append(status_created)
session.add(task)
session.commit()
```

I don't get an error nor new record appears in the table. I would expect an error because of the unique constraint on task_history table unsatisfied. I could then write appropriate logic in my application to handle this case. How does the 'append' method work here? It seems that it doesn't translate directly to INSERT INTO statement. What does it actually do?